# Custom Wix Installer passes details into Product.wxs

Tags: wix

Is there a way to prompt the user to enter a number e.g. 82 on install. Then Wix do the following:

- Installs the service name as "Service Name - M82"
- Install the service to the correct directory with the name of "Service Name - M82"
- Cerate’s an entry in the Programs and Features as "Service Name - M82"

Answer (score 0):

No. Well, two out of three.

- Service display names (and even the underlying service name) are [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609) in the [ServiceInstall table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637) so are easy to override.
- Directories are also easy to override at installation time (though doing so can violate component rules in some esoteric cases).
- However, the Programs and Features name is based on the value of [ProductName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370857), which is a private property and thus doesn't override well at installation time.